# Drupal 7: How to have complete control over a node's layout

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-theming

I'm trying to do a 3 column layout for the homepage of a Drupal 7 site.

I have a region created in the template.

I then have a content type called text_panel which uses the node block module. For each column I just create a new text_panel node, and add it like a block to the region on the homepage.

I then created a file called node--text_panel.tpl.php which contains the following markup:

```
        <div class="span4">
        <h3><?php print $title; ?></h3>            
        <p><?php print $body[0]['value'] ?></p>
    </div>
```

This displays fine, except for the fact that the title gets displayed twice. Drupal outputs it once in an h2 tag, then again as per my node level template file. How do I stop Drupal outputting the h2? I want nodes to display exactly as I define in the template file.

There is a module to get rid of the title, but it does this by wiping out the variable before display, which is no good to me. I want it to display, but just exactly as I dictate.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [display suite](http://drupal.org/project/ds) module.